# Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I have 2 domain models and one Spring REST Controller like below:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID", nullable=false)
private Country country;

// other stuff with getters/setters

}

@Entity
public class Country{

@Id
@Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
private Integer id;

// other stuff with getters/setters

}
```

**Spring REST Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop/services/customers")
public class CustomerRESTController {

   /**
    * Create new customer
    */
    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public com.salesmanager.web.entity.customer.Customer createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody   Customer customer, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        customerService.saveOrUpdate(customer);

        return customer;
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

I am trying to call above REST service with below JSON as body:

```
{
    "firstname": "Tapas",
    "lastname": "Jena",
    "city": "Hyderabad",
    "country": "1"
}
```

Where country code 1 is already there in Country table. The problem is when I am calling this service getting below error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: com.test.model.Customer.country -> com.test.model.Country; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: com.test.model.Customer.country -> com.test.model.Country
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try putting CascadeType.ALL

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID", nullable=false) 

private Country country;
```

Comment: Ok then do one thing. Your customer object has country object with id 1. But that country object is not in persistence state. First get country object by sending country id. Set the  country object retrieved from database into Customer object. Then save customer object. I hope this time it won't give any error.

Comment: Bizarrely, CascadeType.ALL works for me when this doesn't:  `@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })`

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem. Two entities: **Document** and **Status**.
**Document** had a relationship `OneToMany` with **Status**, that represented the history of **Status** the **Document** had.

So, there was a `@NotNull` `@ManyToOne` reference of **Document** inside **Status**.

Also, I needed to know the actual **Status** of **Document**. So, I needed another relationship, this time `@OneToOne`, also `@NotNull`, inside **Document**.

The problem was: how can I persist both entities the first time if both had a `@NotNull` reference to the other?

The solution was: remove `@NotNull` reference from `actualStatus` reference. This way, it was able to persist both entities.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an additional scenario that led me to this exact same error:

**Make sure that any backward references that may exist are not null.**

Specifically in my case, I was using `Mapstruct` to update some fields of the entity, e.g.

```
MyClass newInstance = //...
MyClass dbInstance = repository.findByField(someField);
MyClassMapper.MAPPER.update(dbInstance, newInstance);
repository.save(dbInstance);
```

And my poor implementation of `MyClassMapper` led the backward references of `dbInstance` fields to be set to `null` when they should be pointing back to `dbInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and this is how I solved it:

1st Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Person implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int personId;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private long phoneNumber;
        private String password;
        private String userType;
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "personCustomer", cascade 
        = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Customer customer;
```

2nd Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int customerId;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_customer")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person personCustomer;
```

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/customer/registration")
    public PersonCustomer addCustomer(@RequestBody Person person)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer(person);
        person.setCustomer(customer);
        Customer cust = customerRepo.save(customer);
        logger.info("{}", cust);
        Optional<Person> person_Cust = 
        personRepo.findById(cust.getPersonCustomer().getPersonId());
        Person personNew = person_Cust.get();
        PersonCustomer personCust = new PersonCustomer();

        if(cust.equals(null))
        {   
            personCust.setStatus("FAIL");
            personCust.setMessage("Registration failed");
            personCust.setTimestamp(personCust.timeStamp());
        }
        personCust.setStatus("OK");
        personCust.setMessage("Registration OK");
        personCust.setTimestamp(personCust.timeStamp());
        personCust.setPerson(personNew);

        return personCust;
    }
```

The problem got solved when I added "person.setCustomer(customer);".
As both POJO classes has each others reference, so we have to "set" each others reference before using the JPA repository method(customerRepo.save(customer));

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The solution seems to be to send the JSON like this:

```
{
  "firstname": "Tapas",
  "lastname": "Jena",
  "city": "Hyderabad",
  "country": {"id":"1"}
}
```

I guess `@RequestBody` tries to map an entity not a single field since the **Customer** instance is referencing a **Country** instance.

(I have similarly two entities, joined. In the DB, records for the referenced entity (Country in your case) were already created but the entity creation (Customer in your case) with a json, provided the same error message. For me CascadeType.ALL not helped but the above written change in the JSON solved the problem. For further config of course CascadeType can be considered.)